# Accessing REST end point on machine behind gateway on private network from public Internet

Tags: java, azure, networking, architecture, reverse-proxy

I have a server running at my home, which is behind firewall and gateway. 
This server hosts a REST based service written in Java. I want a mobile application client on a public Internet to be able to access this server.

I do not want to change my gateway/firewall configurations.

What are the standard ways to achieve this setup?

I have thought of following ways:

- To use remote port forwarding.
  I can have a cloud VM, as a landing machine and open SSH and HTTP port on this cloud.
  Remote user will connect via this cloud machine.
  In HTTP case, I can redirect the http packet, and ssh can be done with one hope.
- To use a Cloud relay service.
  I can not use Azure relay service, as they do not provide Java libraries.

I may also require to SSH into the server also from an external network.

What is the suggested way to achieve this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on http://superuser.com/.

Comment: Do you want to have end-users to be able to access your REST endpoint or is it for your own use (like when you are on travel?).

Also, is this for temporary testing or long term reliable use for a service?

Comment: Hi, Why not migrate your REST service into Azure WebApp for Java or Azure VM? It's easy.

Comment: @adarshj, It is for any end user who can access it with credentials. I am looking for a long term solution.

Comment: @PeterPan, My use case does not allow me to do so..

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement your own relay service using Azure Service Bus, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues/ to know how to get started.

```
+---------+ send +----------+ send +------------+ req  +-------------+
|Home Serv| <->  |ServiceBus| <->  |Azure WebApp| <->  |Mobile Client|
+---------+ recv +----------+ recv +------------+ resp +-------------+
```

Explained above:

- Home Service communicates Azure WebApp with messages via Service Bus Queue.
- Mobile Client communicates Azure WebApp with HTTP request & response.
- All communication with ServiceBus above implemented over AMQP or HTTP REST API that can over gateway, but will cause time delay.

Hope it helps. Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very clear. There are multiple ways to achieve it, indeed.  As you are asking for the industry standard, let's avoid posting a comprehensive list of solutions.

IMHO, **VPN is the industry standard, secure way to access any network from internet**. There are many HW/SW implementations, you can find the best one *for you* depending on your infrastructure.

I would look for another solutions just in case your mobile devices wouldn't support VPN.